# Jupyter notebook widgets

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNlYG.jpg)

How can I get a particular product with most quantity in a particular month from Jan-DEC e.g If I select Jan, and product with most quantity is Vicks, it retirns vicks 9000

Comment: Please, you code snippets instead of images in your question

Answer (score 1):

Accordingly your error `IndentationError: unexpected indent` you have a problem with an indent.

You are free to choose the number of spaces of indentation to use, but you then need to stick with it. If you indent one line by 4 spaces, but then indent the next by 3 (or 5, or 19, or ...), you'll get this error.

For your example, you should add one more space in lines 4 and 6 as in line 3.